# Setting height of textbox to height of label text

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can someone provide me an example of how I can set the height of my textbox to fit the height of a label that accompanies it?  As you can see, I have my label and textbox within a fieldset.  The text for my label can be variable so I'm unsure if there are css properties to handle this or it must be set it dynamically.  I should also mention that my labels are populated on the fly when the page loads.  I'm using Asp.net.

[image: http://postimg.org/image/am7xxwr1v/]

```
<fieldset class="input">
<ol>
        <li>
            <asp:Label id="label1" AssociatedControlID="textField1" runat="server">Provide a brief description of the process used to build, monitor and maintain investment portfolios for this strategy.</asp:Label>
            <textarea ID="textField1" runat="server" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label id="label2" AssociatedControlID="textField2" runat="server">What market anomaly or inefficiency are you trying to capture?</asp:Label>          
            <textarea ID="textField2" runat="server" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
        </li>
</ol>
</fieldset>
```

```
fieldset.input
{
float:none;
clear:both;
width:97%;
border:1px solid #C0CED7;
padding:0;
}

fieldset.input ol 
{
list-style:none;
padding: 1em 1em 0;
}

fieldset.input li 
{
float:left;
clear:left;
width:100%;
padding-bottom:1em;
}

fieldset.input label 
{
float:left;
width:15em;
margin-right:3em;
text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: How the heck do you post html here??  I keep trying but it keeps interpreting it literally instead of posting the raw code.

Comment: Paste the HTML, select it all, and click the `{}` button above. :)

Comment: Thanks Kaloyan. HTML is there.

Comment: @mseg Is that the html that is being sent to the browser? I see `<asp:Label...` which might be why the answer given by @frozenhaart is not working for you...

Comment: Yes I'm using the Label .net control.

Comment: In the future, CSS problems need the generated HTML.  Template code is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var labelHeight = $('label').height();
   $('textarea').height(labelHeight);
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/XrcLy/1/

Comment: `+1` because it's actually working, but here's some css included to make it more clear - http://jsfiddle.net/XrcLy/2/

Comment: The above isn't working for me. I posted my html but I should also mention that my labels are dynamically populated.  To post the html above, I had to copy and paste the results.  Could this be why it doesn't resize as in your example?

Comment: @mseg if jQuery is actually an option, you should probably tag your question accordingly to ensure more people see your question.

Comment: @netrunner  I don't know if jquery is my only option but I've went ahead and tagged it as such.

Comment: @mseg you're probably getting more answers that way

Comment: This looks to be a viable solution using the regular label control but not for an asp.net control.

Comment: @mseg You can use it for a ASP.net control, but you have to add to your web.config `<system.web> <pages clientIdMode="static" /></system.web>` otherwise while rendering the page ASP will add to the ID attribute of the element.

Comment: @mseg you can capture the asp.net control using its ID. eg: `var labelHeight = $('#label1').height();`